# CakePHP querying the wrong table

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model

Something very weird is happening. The following code:

```
$this->Behaviors->load("Containable");
    $this->contain(array(
            "UsersVersion"=>array("FilesUsersVersion")
        )
    );

    $draft=$this->findById($document_id);
```

Is throwing the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'FilesUsersVersion.users_version_id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `FilesUsersVersion`.`id`, `FilesUsersVersion`.`template_id`, `FilesUsersVersion`.`name`, `FilesUsersVersion`.`text`, `FilesUsersVersion`.`created`, `FilesUsersVersion`.`modified`, `FilesUsersVersion`.`users_version_id` FROM `drafts` AS `FilesUsersVersion` WHERE `FilesUsersVersion`.`users_version_id` IN (119, 120)
```

Analyzing the SQL, it is querying the wrong table, and the fields (except for the `users_version_id`) are from `drafts` table instead of `files_users_version` table.

I have cleared cache/models and cache/persistent.

Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. The mistake was in the association className.

Thanks any way.